# How to customize GRUB menu entries (e.g. the name)?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I want to change the names of my os's in my grub and i want to change the default os...

my grub version is "GNU GRUB1.99-21ubuntu3.14"

I also want to know about any bugs that affect this GNU GRUB... please be detailed but keep in mind i'm not a programmer i don't know very much i know how to operate terminal but thats about it ... please list instructions in a step to step bases.... thank you very much

The OS i have installed are Ubuntu 12.04 and kubuntu 12.04 both have had the latest security updates... Kubuntu installed Memtest in the grub too....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take a look at [GRUB Customizer](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1664134).

Comment: "Terminal" Are you sure that my Grub is Grub2 and not Legacy Grub, or some other type of Grub? .... I can't afford do mess up my Grub....

Comment: Yes 12.04 by default installs GRUB 2 with a version number of 1.99~something. GRUB legacy has a version number of 0.99~something. It may be a bit confusing, but that is how the projects naming/numbering convention is.